# Typescript setup w/ Meteor 1.5 - cannot find module meteor/meteor

Tags: javascript, typescript, meteor

I followed [the blog post](https://medium.com/@bwhitty/meteor-1-3-typescript-and-react-keep-it-simple-cb83ea248944) but that didn't work. Here's my commit: https://github.com/Falieson/react15-meteor1.5/commit/b0c5ccd4f940d980a227789e151c9b1ffb8f71cf

Error

```
$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/Private/ReactMeteorExample ]]]]]
=> Started proxy.
client/index.tsx (2, 24): Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.
```

Installed

```
$ meteor add barbatus:typescript
$ meteor npm install --save @types/meteor @types/react
```

tsconfig.json

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "meteor-typings"
    ]
```

Additional question: should the typings be dev dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"types"` section in the tsconfig file should be unnecessary as you don't have the meteor-typings directory ('meteor-typings' was an old way of doing things).

As the `@types` packages are only `.d.ts` files it shouldn't matter whether they are standard or dev dependencies. Personally, I'd leave them as non-dev.

To fix the issue you're getting, add a file at the top level called `typings.d.ts` and put in it a reference to the packages you want to reference, e.g.:

`/// <reference types="@types/meteor" />`

You may need to add the react types or they may get added automatically due to the jsx = react definition, but it seemed to run without any errors after I added the above.

The typescript docs suggest that the `@types` files should be included automatically, but I don't know why they're not. They weren't picked up when I removed the "types" above.

An alternative solution is to specify the types explicitly in the tsconfig.json file e.g.:

    `...
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [ "meteor" ]`

Here's the relevant bit of the TS docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types
This section starts by saying 'By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation.' but goes on to explain how "typeRoots" and "types" can be configured in the `tsconfig.json` file.